# Google Suite SAMLRequest URL Issue

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 library to integrate with Google Suite SSO and the library is NOT generating/calling the Saml Request Url correct:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=XXXXXXXX?SAMLRequest=XXXXXXX
```

I think the correct should be:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=XXXXXXXX&SAMLRequest=XXXXXXX
```

This is the Google Suite Single Sign-On Url passed to the library:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=XXXXXXXX
```

There is any library config/parameter that I can set to fix the issue? 
Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Google Suite SSO support SAML 2.0 Authn Request with a POST binding. The problem can be solved by using the Saml2PostBinding instead of the Saml2RedirectBinding.

The Saml2RedirectBinding support a destination URL with "?" like a Google Suite SSO URL from version 3.1.0-beta2 https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/3.1.0-beta2.

Please let me know if the beta version works with Google Suite SSO.

*** Update ***

[Version 4.0.0](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.0.0) is released supporting Saml2RedirectBinding destination URL with "?".